# How does git handle Windows NTFS junction points?

Tags: windows, git, ntfs

It seems that Git ignores NTFS Junction Points. Can this behavior be changed? It is probably trying to avoid them for a multitude of reasons (issues that could pop up), but a person who knows what he or she is doing can use them with caution.

Thanks to any/all answers!

Comment: What would you want git to do with them?

Comment: Treat them as a normal directory.

Comment: Just a guess, but it probably treats them exactly as if they were directory symlinks.  So if there is an option to control what Git does for symlinks, try that.

Comment: And my discoveries so far show me it treats them *dfifferently* than symlinks. It entirely ignores them by default, while symlinks it stores as symlinks by default. I don't think they put much time into Windows caveats.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, treating junctions as symlinks would be wrong, but something I've come to expect from developers that just don't get it, even at Microsoft (looking at you WSL). They're always mount points, not just when they target the root path of the special "Volume{GUID}" volume device name. In particular, when parsing a path in the kernel, traversed junction mount points are remembered so ".." components in relative symlinks can traverse them as regular directories, like Unix mountpoints (e.g. "foo\junction\..\bar" -> "foo\bar"), whereas a directory symlink always resolves to its target.

Comment: Also, Unix-like code that recreates symlinks via `readlink` is wrong if it naively handles Windows mountpoints as symlinks. A mountpoint can only target a local device, which allows them to be resolved on the server side in remote paths, regardless of the number of servers that path parsing has to jump through. It is thus nonsensical and dangerous to resolve a remote junction via `readlink` and recreate it via `symlink` when copying a remote tree. It must be copied as a regular directory, which gets complicated in the presence of cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Git under Windows treats NTFS Junction Points as some sort of 'ignored entity'. It recognizes they aren't real, aren't quite a symlink, so ignores them.

I never did answer this to my satisfaction, or get an answer, thus this is the best I have (not having all the time in the world to research something so tiny).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for possible incorrect use of terminology...

I sometimes want to create a git repo that has contents from various places in the filesystem.
So I create a top level folder then include several NTFS junctions (which look like directory symbolic links) to that folder. I then initialize a git repo in the top level. The git repo has the contents of the FTFS junctions. Greta. I created this with plain command line Git for Windows and it works well for me over the years.

However Gitkraken won't work with this setup. It won't even open the repo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).