# How does git handle windows shortcuts?

Tags: windows, git

I have a directory of shortcuts that I've committed to a git repo.  It appears that Windows modifies the shortcut file contents but retains what the shortcut points to.

So `git` shows these shortcut files as different but just reports them as binary differences so there is no way to know what really changed.

I ended up writing a cygwin shell script `git diff-shortcuts` to properly show if a shortcut file has changed but it's so clunky I'd like to see how others deal with this situation (if they do).   For the shortcuts that haven't really changed, I run `git checkout -- MyToolbar\shortcut-22.lnk`

The reason for the shortcuts is simple.  I have a set of scripts that I've committed to a git repo and clone them onto a local windows host when I do development.  For example, `c:\loc\myenv`.  I then add the shortcuts to my Windows taskbar, by right clicking and adding a "new toolbar..." and point to `c:\loc\myenv\MyToolbar` which has all of my desired shortcuts.

I think think this question will largely be ignored but wanted to have it here in case others might find it useful.

See also [How does git handle Windows NTFS junction points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640986/how-does-git-handle-windows-ntfs-junction-points)

I expect to answer this question if no one else provides an answer.

Comment: I've never tried it, but here's [instructions to set up a program to generate text to diff from binary files](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/configuration/diff-binary-files-docx-odt-pdf-with-git.html) and plumb it into git attributes (and from the Git docs: [diffs of binary files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files)), and there are a few programs that will parse .lnk files to text, e.g. [lnk-parse](https://github.com/lcorbasson/lnk-parse) or [lp](https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=11), but I haven't tried any to recommend them.

Comment: It sounds like you really want an 'ignore unless some specific attributes changed' though, or 'reset unless ...'. I'm not sure there's a git hook to do that pre-status though alas.

Comment: I'd also guess that if you made your shortcut files read-only then Windows wouldn't update whatever metadata it changes in them on use.